# Unable to access some topics in Matlab

Tags: matlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am completely new to ROSbag. I have a bag file and would like to work with it in MATLAB.

I canview the messages for one of my topics using:

```
>> bag = rosbag('HMB_1.bag');
>> bagselect_c = select(bag, 'Topic', '/center_camera/image_color/compressed');
>> msgs_c = readMessages(bagselect_c);
```

when I try to do the same for another topic, I get an error:

```
>> bagselect= select(bag, 'Topic', '/vehicle/steering_report');
>> msgstemp = readMessages(bagselect);
Error using robotics.ros.BagSelection/deserializeMessages (line 445)
Java exception occurred:
org.ros.exception.RosMessageRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dbw_mkz_msgs.SteeringReport

    at org.ros.internal.message.definition.MessageDefinitionReflectionProvider.get(MessageDefinitionReflectionProvider.java:66)

    at org.ros.internal.message.DefaultMessageFactory.newFromType(DefaultMessageFactory.java:42)

    at org.ros.internal.message.DefaultMessageDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultMessageDeserializer.java:42)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dbw_mkz_msgs.SteeringReport

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at org.ros.internal.message.definition.MessageDefinitionReflectionProvider.get(MessageDefinitionReflectionProvider.java:62)

    ... 2 more


Error in robotics.ros.BagSelection/readMessages (line 195)
            msgs = obj.deserializeMessages(obj.MessageList, rows);
```

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256893/unable-to-access-some-topics-in-matlab/) by [fadiak](https://answers.ros.org/users/29674/fadiak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to use custom ros message support. You have to use rosgenmsg.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/rosgenmsg.html

---

Originally posted by [snehesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31342/snehesh/) with karma: 31 on 2017-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0